# Intellij how to set gradle property -Pname=value

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, properties

Intellij: how to set gradle property -Pname=value?

build from command line:

```
gradlew assemble -PuseNewLibs=true
```

How to do this inside Intellij?

The property tells gradle to use different dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In your [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html), you can add `-PuseNewLibs=true` to the `Program arguments:` section.

Comment: Is the run configuration for JVM options only? thanks.